# Property that can rearrange components when I am changing size of windows applications

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, automatic-properties

Are there any property of a form or a component by which components of windows applications created using Visual Studio will be arranged automatically when I changed the windows size or maximized - restored the window? If not, How can I do it manually?

Comment: To clarify: you want to know if there's anything built into WinForms that'll remember your applications last window position?

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe: No... I want to know the property by which components of a form will automatically rearranged when I am changing the size of the form.

Comment: Oh, OK. You want to know how to automatically move/resize child windows when the parent window is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several.  Starting with the Dock and Anchor properties of a control, good for simple layouts with no more than, say, 3 controls across.  Then the TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel controls, they automatically arrange the controls inside of them.  Respectively in a grid and a flow layout.

For the really tough layout cases you could implement the form's Resize event and calculate Location and Size properties yourself.  That's rarely necessary.